# Determining $|DE|$

Tags: geometry

[image]

Let's assume that $\triangle ABC$, $\triangle ADE$ are equilateral triangles, and that $|DC| = 1, |EC| = 2$. How could we find $|DE|$?

Since $\triangle ABC$, $\triangle ADE$ are equilateral triangles, if $\angle BAD = \alpha$, $\angle DAC = \beta$, and $\angle GAE = \theta$, then $\alpha+\beta = 60^{\circ}$ and $\beta + \theta = 60^{\circ}$, from which we conclude that $\alpha = \theta$. And since $\angle DCG = 60^{\circ}$,

$$|DE| = \sqrt{5+4\cos(60^{\circ}+\angle GCE)}$$

But for $\angle GCE$ to be determined, we'll have to determine $\angle GDC$ and $\angle GEC$.

Comment: Where is point $G$?

Comment: As hinted in [Sathvik's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4621707/89922), $AECD$ is a cyclic quadrilateral. Then these opposite angles add to $180^\circ$: $\angle DCE + \angle DAE = 180^\circ$ or $\angle DCE + 60^\circ = 180^\circ$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$\angle ACB=\angle AED=60^{\circ}\implies AECD$ is a cyclic quadrilateral.

Using [Ptolemy's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_theorem), $|AC|=|EC|+|DC|=3$. Apply the cosine rule in $\triangle ABD$ to find $|AD|=|DE|$.